# Insert data to SQL Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I've been trying to make a signup form in Visual Studio, but it doesn't seem to work. The idea is that when you press Button1, the values from Textbox1 and Textbox2 are stored in the database.

```
Public Class SignUp
Dim mysqlConn As Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
Dim command As Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    mysqlConn = New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    mysqlConn.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\NewFolder1\Members.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim reader As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    Try
        mysqlConn.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "Insert into [User] ('username', 'password') VALUES (" & TextBox1.Text & " AND " & TextBox2.Text & ")" 'virker ikke
        command = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, mysqlConn)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader
        mysqlConn.Close()

        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        mysqlConn.Dispose()

    End Try
```

It gives me an error which says the columns are wrong.

Comment: Are you getting an exception? What is exactly happening?

Comment: you are using a datareader to execute a query. try using the ExecuteNonQuery method on the connection object.

Comment: You also need to either make your username and password values parameters or wrap them in single quotes

Comment: @soohoonigan 
Like this?
    "Insert into [User] ("username", "password")

Comment: Your values should probably be separated by commas and not `AND`, also you need to include single-quotes around the values like this:
`query = "Insert into [User] ('username', 'password') VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "')" 'virker ikke`

Comment: No, the values should definitely be passed as Parameters and passwords should never be stored as plain text

Comment: @Plutonix I didnt ask about hashing passwords sweety <3

Comment: @Jeremy How exactly do i do that?

Comment: ...and therein lies the problem.

Comment: @ElroySkimms It gives me an error and says the columns are wrong, which they shouldnt be..

Comment: @Plutonix So youre saying that if i hash my passwords, i wont have a problem?

Comment: I'm saying just because you dont ask about something doesnt mean it is not a problem.  Your code will (still) fail with names like `O'Brian` or `D'Artagnan`

Comment: @Plutonix Fair point, sorry if i seemed "agressive" or w/e, im just stressed out enough by this already, without worrying about security ;)

Comment: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Comment: @Plutonix 
Banter aside, do you have any suggestion for this to work? It returns

Comment: my apologies, it is on the Command object. Have a look at the documentation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove the single quotes from the column names. Try this: `query = "Insert into [User] (username, password) VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "')" 'virker ikke`

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look something like this:

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Signup

    Private Sub bnSignup_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnSignup.Click
        Dim connStr = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\NewFolder1\Members.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        Dim query = "INSERT INTO [User] ([username], [password]) VALUES (@username, @password)"

        'TODO: Hash the password to save it in the database.

        Try
            Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
                Using command As New Sqlcommand(query, sqlConn)
                    command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@username", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Value = tbUsername.Text})
                    command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@password", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Value = tbPassword.Text})

                    sqlConn.Open()
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    sqlConn.Close()

                End Using
            End Using

            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

    ' Other code...

End Class
```

The [`Using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) construct takes care of disposing of unmanaged resources for you, even if an exception occurs.

The use of SqlParameters aids the prevention of SQL injection attacks and allows characters like apostrophes to be passed to SQL Server without any problems.

It is a good idea to give your controls meaningful names.

For information on how to store passwords securely, I suggest having a read of [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

Comment: This code block doesnt seem to change anything in my database..?

Comment: How are you looking at what is in the database? I suggest using [SSMS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx) so that there are no issues with cached data or something being out-of-step in your program.

Comment: Its a local database, but ill try ssms

Answer (score 0):

This should get your code working. It's not good programming practice at all, but it is what you are asking for:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim mysqlConn As Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim command As Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        mysqlConn = New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        mysqlConn.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\NewFolder1\Members.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim RowsAffected As Integer
        Try
            mysqlConn.Open()
            Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO [User] (username, password) VALUES (@Username, @Password)"
            command = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, mysqlConn)
                        Dim paramUsername As New SqlClient.SqlParameter() With {.ParameterName = "@Username", .Value = TextBox1.Text, .Size = 50, .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar}
                        Dim paramPassword As New SqlClient.SqlParameter() With {.ParameterName = "@Password", .Value = TextBox2.Text, .Size = 50, .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar}

            command.Parameters.Add(paramUsername)
            command.Parameters.Add(paramPassword)
            RowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery
            mysqlConn.Close()
            If RowsAffected > 0 Then MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            mysqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

This version uses SQL parameters, which should protect against SQL injection and values like `O'Brian`.

As others have said (and we told you yesterday too), storing passwords in plain text really is a bad idea. I know, you didn't ask for that advice, but if you are using this code for ANYTHING public facing, you need to hash your passwords and store the hashed string.

-E

Comment: It says that string cannot be converted into integer, more precisely in the textboxes. Help..?

Comment: I apologize, my sql parameter constructors were wrong. I have corrected them now.